# SQL date (specific date)

Tags: sql, oracle, date, between

I want to get the list of offices name that was working for us before 2015-01-01 and after 2016-01-01 but not between 2015-01-01  and 2016-01-01.

If try to put NOT BETWEEN then it will basically give me the result excluding that two dates.can somebody solve this ?

```
select distinct office_name
from history
where date not between  '01-jan-2015' and '01-jan-2016'
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Why not try `date < ‘01-jan-2015’ and date > ‘01-Jan-2016’`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want aggregation:

```
select office_name
from history
group by office_name
having sum(case when date between date '2015-01-01' and '2016-01-01' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;;
```

Comment: ..it perfectly works for me ..thats what i was looking for..thank you so much